# flutter admob remove on back button

Tags: flutter, admob

Could someone please point me onto the right direction on intergrating admob.

I was able to get the plugin https://pub.dev/packages/ads show ads, but I could not get it to unload the ad when a user changed widget.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final article;
  Ads appAds;

  final String appId = "ca-app-pub-4999865903647931~XXXXXXXXXX";
  final String bannerUnitId = "ca-app-pub-4999865903647931/XXXXXXXxX";


  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  SecondRoute({Key key, @required this.article}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    appAds = Ads(
      appId,
      bannerUnitId: bannerUnitId,
      // screenUnitId: screenUnitId,
      // keywords: <String>['ibm', 'computers'],
      // contentUrl: 'http://www.ibm.com',
      //childDirected: false,
      testDevices: ['SM_A305YN:5554'],
      testing: true,
      listener: eventListener,
    );
    appAds.showBannerAd(anchorType: AnchorType.top, anchorOffset: 120);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        title: Text(article['title']),
        leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: (){
              appAds.hideBannerAd();
            }
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                      child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Card(
                          child: new Container(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Image.network(article['image'], fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                                        Html(data: article['content']),

                                      ]
                                  ),
                              ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      )

      )
    );


  }
}
```

I want when a user hits the back button it removes the appAds banner.

Comment: Did you try making `SecondRoute` a stateful widget? You could try wrapping the `hideBannerAd` function in a setState. Not sure if that will work, I'm not super familiar with that package

Comment: @DerekFredrickson what is the best admob package?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Stateful widget instead a Stateless and call the dispose method when you want to stop the ads.

```
_ads?.dispose()
```